# Accent in JTable displayed in Eclipse but not in a .jar

Tags: java, utf-8, jtable, non-ascii-characters

I am displaying a csv file (with a UTF-8 encoding and french accents) in a JTable. To read the file I use the following lines (s_path is a String which corresponds to the path of the csv file):

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(s_path),',');

do{
    String currentLine = reader.readNext();
    ...
}
```

To display the content of a cell in the JTable I use html (i.e., "html" and "body" markup and eventually "br" markups if a cell is displayed on several lines)

It works fine when I execute the project in Eclipse. However, if I export a .jar file from my project (and use the exact same csv files), the accent are not displayed (e.g., see the following image).

[image: accent not displayed in JTable with a .har]

I really don't have any idea how to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Don't hesitate to ask for more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file really is encoded using UTF8, you should use

```
reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(s_path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ',');
```

to read it. The way you're doing it, it uses the default charset of your platform, which is probably not UTF8.